# поиск ближайшего элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript, reactjs

всем привет)б подскажите как решить этот таск
у нас есть две кнопки - 1. добавляет секунды а 2. отнимает их и
смысл в том чтоб найти ближайший элемент в массиве после того как добавил или отнял секунду к текущему

```
const findClosestTime = (currentTimestamp, arrayTimestamps, second) => {
        const lastTimestamp = arrayTimestamps[arrayTimestamps.length - 1]?.timestamp
        const firstTimestamp = arrayTimestamps[0]?.timestamp
        const time = new Date(currentTimestamp);

        time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + second);
        let result;

        const arrayTest = []
```

**тут должен быть цикл что ищет ближайший элемент в массиве**

```
        return arrayTimestamps.findIndex(({timestamp}) => timestamp === result);
    }


const plus15Second = () => {
        const timestampIndex = findClosestTime(inferences[currentFrame]?.timestamp, inferences, +30);
        if (currentFrame <= inferences.length) {
            changeCurrentStates(timestampIndex)
        }
    }
    const minus15Second = () => {
        const timestampIndex = findClosestTime(inferences[currentFrame]?.timestamp, inferences, -30);
        if (currentFrame !== 0) {
            changeCurrentStates(timestampIndex)
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: добавил и написал где я чутка застрял

Comment: Хорошо, добавили, но что конкретно у вас не получилось.

Comment: не знаю как правильно написать цикл для поиска ближайшего элемента в массиве - если я правильно понимаю то когда ты жмешь на добавить секунды то нужно искать ближайший элемент справа и если отнимать то искать ближайший слева

Comment: Я JavaScript не знаю, просто попросил привести подробности что-бы другие участники смогли вам помочь

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < arrayTimestamps.length; i++) {
            if (time > arrayTimestamps[i]?.timestamp && time < lastTimestamp) {
                result = arrayTimestamps[i + 1]?.timestamp
            }
        }

писал как-то вот такое решения но оно правильно работает только в одном случаи когда отнимаешь то до конца не доходит

Comment: я понял) ну надеюсь что люди поймут - а то я слегка застрял и не могу подобрать правильное решения

Comment: хорошо а как-бы вы делали на другом языке ? ну на котором вы пишите ?

Comment: Ну у вас задание немного странное, не могу понять...

Comment: окай, ща попробую более детальней расписать) 
к примеру у нас есть массив unixTimes 
хочу прыгать по ним но типа через добавления и отнимание секунд у текущего,

нажал к примеру на +30 секунд и он  добавил секунды к текущему unixTime и потом мы ищем в массиве ближайший элемент что стоит справа от этого что мы изменили